# Sublime 2 can not find file in the path (LaTeX plugin)

Tags: path, latex, sublimetext2

I have a project in directory A and files that I use in all my projects are in directory B.
When I moved a .sty file from A to B, the main .tex file does not compile anymore.
The error is that the .sty file was not found. I am puzzled because:

1. Directory B **is** included in the path of the project.
2. I cleaned (deleted manually) all the auxiliary files used in the previous compilations.
3. I refreshed the project folders .

Did anyone had similar problems? Suggestions?

Comment: Are on an OSX system by any chance, and are you moving your *.sty files outside of the normal path?: `$PATH:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin`.  It would seem to me that the *.sty files either need to be in the path or in the root directory with the *.tex file.

Comment: Take a look at `LaTeX.sublime-build` inside the LatexTools directory within packages.

Comment: @Lawlist please consider posting your comment as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The file `LaTeX.sublime-build`, within the Sublime Text folder `. . . /Packages/LaTeXTools`, contains a `$PATH` for different operating systems.

For **example**, Sublime Text 2 on an OSX operating system, has a file located at `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/LaTeXTools/LaTeX.sublime-build`.  The relevant line of code for a MacTeX TexLive 2012 installation is `"path": "$PATH:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin",`.  The plugin `LaTeXTools` looks in that path for `*.sty` files that are a part of the TexLive installation.  While it may be possible (under some circumstances) to place the `*.sty` files within the working directory of the `*.tex` file, this particular plugin looks to the path mentioned hereinabove.  So one option would be to add additional locations to the $PATH to suit the needs of the user, or simply place the `*.sty` files within the path that is pre-defined by the plugin developer.